# Dynamic Programming - Adding up N Integers

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm studying for a final and the professor gave us a practice problem to prepare, but it's extremely difficult and I've been hacking at it for hours with no luck. Here it is:

[image]

It's driving me bonkers so I hope somebody out there can show me how it's done!

Thanks

Comment: It's better if you copied the question as text rather than as graphics, to enable finding the question in the future.

Comment: These problem is pretty similar to matrix chain multiplication problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication, because you need to associate two numbers with a cost function for that, the operation is binary, It solve find out the minimum cost for put parenthesis.

Comment: Raphael: I've tried the following recurrences without any luck: 'Cik + Cj-i,j i <= k < j' 'Cik + Ci+k,j i <= k < j' 'Cik + C1+k,j i <= k < j' 'Cik + Cj-k,j i <= k < j' 'Cik + Cj-1,j i <= k < j' but I think I'm probably going about it entire the wrong way

Comment: @KrispyK Can you ask for prof if this problem can be solved in $O(n\log n)$?

Comment: Prof is away at a conference. He won't even be there to proctor the exam. :(

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each $i < j$, compute the series of operations minimizing the cost of evaluating the sum $a_i + \cdots + a_j$, in increasing order of $j-i$. If $j = i+1$ then the cost is simply $a_i + a_j$. Otherwise, suppose that the last operation is $(a_i + \cdots + a_k) + (a_{k+1} + \cdots + a_j)$. Go over all $k$, and for each $k$ compute the minimal cost using the dynamic programming table. Deduce the best $k$ and the minimal cost.

Comment: As always your dp hints are pretty good. Actually, I'm consider don't post my answer, not now. Give the chances to @KrispyK construct the relation.

Comment: I'm a little lost at where you say go over all k, and for each k, compute the minimal cost using the dynamic programming table. Deduce the best k and the minimal cost.

So a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 < in the example.

So by going over all k, k=1,k=2,k=3,k=4,k=5, then I'm not sure what to do at each k. For example, if k = 2, do I take the value at S12, and the value at S35? What do I do with those if I do?

Comment: Well, you won't get any practice if I give you any more hints. At the exam even this kind of sketch won't be available. Try to complete it on your own for a couple of hours.

Comment: Ok, here is my thought process
Consider a pool/data structure that holds our initial values: [7,2,4,5,3]. We take the smallest value in that pool (2), and the smallest adjacent value (4) and we get its cost (6). Add that cost to our sum (=6). We remove 2,4 from the pool, and add 6. Our pool now has [7,5,3,6]. We take the smallest in pool (3) and its smallest adjacent (5) and get that cost (8). Remove 5,3 and add 8 to pool and to sum (sum=14), pool [7,6,8]. Take 6 and 7, cost is 13, add it to pool and sum, remove 6,8 from pool. Sum=27, pool [8,13], 8+13=21, add it sum= 48 << the sol'n.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to systematically pull the cost from the Sij matrix when I try to get the costs.

Comment: You're suggesting a greedy approach. I'm not sure that this problem can be solved using a greedy algorithm (though it is conceivable). At any rate, you are asked specifically for a DP algorithm, so you'd better come up with one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm stuck. I'm struggling to figure this one out. Maybe another small hint? Your original answer showed me how to build Sij, which is given in the question. I'm struggling to make the leap from where you say:  Go over all k, and for each k compute the minimal cost using the dynamic programming table. Deduce the best k and the minimal cost.

Comment: My table is different from the $S$ table. It contains the (value of) the optimal solution for each *subproblem*, where a subproblem here is adding up $a_i+\cdots+a_j$ in the most efficient way.

Comment: I've tried the following recurrences without any luck: 
'Cik + Cj-i,j i <= k < j'
'Cik + Ci+k,j i <= k < j'
'Cik + C1+k,j i <= k < j'
'Cik + Cj-k,j i <= k < j'
'Cik + Cj-1,j i <= k < j'

It's 4:30 am, losing my mind. At this point, I think I'm unlikely to get it without another hint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19315/discussion-between-krispyk-and-yuval-filmus).